# Count how many even or odd numbers there in the program in C++

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop

The program asks the users for numbers until the total of the numbers is greater than 30. Also, the user has to count how many numbers are even and how many are odd.
I can get the first part of the problem but i am having trouble with the counting part.

i.e.

> Total is 0
>   Please enter an integer: 20
>   Total is 20
>   You had 1 even numbers and 0 odd numbers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main (){
   int integer;
   int total = 20;
   int even_count = 0;
   int odd_count = 0;
   cout << "Total is 0" << endl;
   cout << "Please enter an integer: ";
   cin >> integer;
   cout << integer << endl;
   while ( total <= 30){
      cout << "Total is " << total << endl;
      cout << "Please enter an integer: ";
      cin >> integer;
      cout << integer << endl;
      total = integer + total;  
   }
   if (integer % 2 == 0) {
         even_count = even_count + 1;
      }
   if (integer % 2 != 0){
         odd_count = odd_count + 1;
      }
   cout << "You had " << even_count << " even numbers and "; 
   cout << odd_count << " odd numbers.";
   cout << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is the trouble? your example output is fine, no?

Comment: You are testing the integer every time, not after all input has gone, right?

Comment: you initialize `total` to `20` and then print  "Total is 0", maybe thats all you have to fix?

Comment: read again your code and pay close attention to what parts are inside the loop and what parts are outside.

Comment: Also, try entering a number that isn't `20`, e.g. `5`

Comment: when you exit the loop the variable `integer`contains the last value entered by the user which is either **even** or **odd**.

Comment: Use an array to store all integers entered by user, and then a `for` loop to count odd and even.

Comment: Ive tried moving the if statement inside the loop but it still would not produce the outcome.

Comment: `if (integer & 1) { /* I'm odd */ } else { /* I'm even */ }` avoids the division inherent in modulo.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main (){
   int integer=0;
   int total = 0;
   int even_count = 0;
   int odd_count = 0;
   cout << "Total is " << total << endl;
   while ( total <=30 && integer <=30){
      cout << "Please enter an integer: ";
      cin >> integer;
      total = integer + total;  
      if(total <=30){
        cout << "Total is " << total << endl;
      }
      if (integer % 2 == 0) {
        even_count = even_count + 1;
      }
      if (integer % 2 == 1){
        odd_count = odd_count + 1;
      }
   }   
   cout << "You had " << even_count << " even numbers and " << odd_count << 
" odd numbers." << endl;   
}
```

Here is a sample output:
    `Total is 0
    Please enter an integer: 25
    Total is 25
    Please enter an integer: 5
    Total is 30
    Please enter an integer: 1
    You had 0 even numbers and 3 odd numbers.`